# sap.m.table multi checkbox make it READ ONLY - On Condition + SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

This is my first post to Stack, appreciate the work you guys do, amazing.

I have a sap.m.table sap ui5 and i have 4 records

out of 4, 2 are selected by default, i want to disable the preselected once based on condition.

I have tried below code but its not working, any input please?

**View**

/results' }" **mode="MultiSelect"**

**Controller logic**

```
                //--->disable the selected department checkboxes
                var tbl = that.getView().byId('idImpactTable');
                var header = tbl.$().find('thead');
                var selectAllCb = header.find('.sapMCb');
                selectAllCb.remove();

                tbl.getItems().forEach(function(r) {
                var obj = r.getBindingContext("impactModel").getObject();
                var oStatus = obj.COMPLETED;
                var cb = r.$().find('.sapMCb');
                var oCb = sap.ui.getCore().byId(cb.attr('id'));
                    if (oStatus === "X") {
                    oCb.setSelected(true);
                    oCb.setEnabled(false);
                    } else {
                        oCb.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                 });
```

[Multiselect Mode Table - Make selected check box read only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khJLM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Last time I tried this I found it easiest to use the `updateFinished` event on the table, and then use an internal property of the column list item, like so:

```
onTableUpdateFinished: function (oEvent) {
    oEvent.getSource().getItems().forEach(function (item) {
        var data = item.getBindingContext().getObject();
        item._oMultiSelectControl.setEnabled(!data.IsEnabled); //whatever your check is
    });
}
```

You'll have to find a way to *keep them disabled* though when using the `Select All` checkbox at the top of the table. I ended up extending `sap.m.Table` to accomplish that, there might be easier ways...

---

My extension is like this

```
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/m/Table"
], function(Control) {

  return Control.extend("myapp.controls.MyTable", {
    updateSelectAllCheckbox: function(oEvent) {
        if (this._selectAllCheckBox && this.getMode() === "MultiSelect") {
            var aItems = this.getItems();
            var iSelectedItemCount = this.getSelectedItems().length; 
            var iSelectableItemCount = aItems.filter(function(oItem) {
                //standard table does not check if the item is enabled
                return oItem.getSelected() || oItem._oMultiSelectControl.getEnabled();
            }).length;

            // set state of the checkbox by comparing item length and selected item length
            this._selectAllCheckBox.setSelected(aItems.length > 0 && iSelectedItemCount === iSelectableItemCount);
        }
    }
  });
});
```

And just the standard renderer

```
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/m/TableRenderer"
], function(Control) {

  return Control.extend("myapp.controls.MyTableRenderer", {
  });
});
```

I suppose I could have extended the ColumnListItem but that was more effort than I wanted to put into the table extension

Comment: Thank you Jorg, really appriciate your feedback, i have managed to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the solution, please find sample code to achieve.

```
                //--->disable the selected department checkboxes
                var tbl = that.getView().byId("idImpactTable");
                var header = tbl.$().find("thead");
                var selectAllCb = header.find(".sapMCb");
                selectAllCb.remove();

                var aItems = that.byId("idImpactTable").getItems();
                //---> Check individual item property value and select the item
                aItems.forEach(function(oItem) {
                    debugger;
                    //---> If using OData Model items Binding, get the item object
                    var mObject = oItem.getBindingContext().getObject();
                    var sPath = oItem.getBindingContextPath();
                    var completed = oItem.oBindingContexts.impactModel.getProperty("COMPLETED");

                    //--->get the id of Multi Checkbox
                    var cb = oItem.$().find(".sapMCb");
                    var oCb = sap.ui.getCore().byId(cb.attr("id"));

                    if (completed === "X") {
                        oCb.setEditable(false);
                        oItem.setSelected(true);
                        oItem.getCells()[4].setEnabled(false);
                    } else {
                        oItem.setSelected(false);
                    }
                });
```

Thank you,
Jacob.Kata

Answer (score -1):

```
//--->disable the selected department checkboxes
var tbl = that.getView().byId('idImpactTable');
        
tbl.getItems().forEach(function(r) {   
// this makes the trick --->
var oMultiSelCtrl = r.getMultiSelectControl();
oMultiSelCtrl.setDisplayOnly( true );
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.